# Trying to run a docker server

Tags: python, docker, flask

folks i have a web folder which has the following files inside:
app.py
Docker file
requirements.txt
outside that file i have a docker-compose.yml

the code is as follows:
app.py

```
code...

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

on the requirements txt:

```
Flask
flask_restful
```

on the DockerFile:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./app.py" ]
```

and on the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web: 
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

i go on the terminal and i run
docker compose build and
docker compose up

and server runs as below:

```
se 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
PS C:\Users\sarandis\Desktop\Python API\web service> docker compose up   
webservice-web-1  |  * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading) 
webservice-web-1  |  * Environment: production                                                                                                                        0.6s 
webservice-web-1  |    WARNING: This is a development server. 
Do not use it in a production deployment.
webservice-web-1  |    Use a production WSGI server instead.  
webservice-web-1  |  * Debug mode: off                        Do not use it in a production deployment.
webservice-web-1  |  * Running on all addresses.
webservice-web-1  |    WARNING: This is a development server. 
Do not use it in a production deployment.
webservice-web-1  |  * Running on http://172.18.0.2:5000/ (PreDo not use it in a production deployment.ss CTRL+C to quit)                                            ss CTRL+C to quit)
Gracefully stopping...
```

the problem i have when i click on the url it provides me it says that the site cant be reached!!
why is that? what em i doing wrong?

note that when i do flask run the app runs at it should and all the get and post requests work fine!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to access http://localhost:5000 instead of the provided URL?